# Add new object to list

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to learn oop but stuck in somewhere for hours. 
Here is my main class:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Class1 cls = new Class1("",0);
     cls.kitapAdi= "book name";
     cls.sayfaSayisi= 22;
     bool sonuc = cls.AddBook(cls);
}
```

And object class(Class1):

```
 public Class1(string ali, int mehmet)
    {
        this.kitapAdi = ali;
        this.sayfaSayisi = mehmet;
    }

    List<Class1> books = new List<Class1>();     

    private string kitapAdi;
    private int sayfaSayisi;

    public int SayfaSayisi
    {
        get { return sayfaSayisi; }
        set { sayfaSayisi = value; }
    }

    public string KitapAdi
    {
        get { return kitapAdi; }
        set { kitapAdi = value; }
    }

    public bool AddBook(Class1 kitap)
    {
        try
        {
            books.Add(new Class1 ( kitapAdi = kitap.kitapAdi, sayfaSayisi = kitap.sayfaSayisi ));

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It does not give any error but nothing happens. When I debug, I seethat AddBook method of Class1 takes correct datas but it does not add this to books list.

Comment: I think [tag:arraylist] is a wrong tag here, there is an *inferior* version of strong-typed `List<>` in C# called [`ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: How have you checked whether the book was correctly added to the list or not? Since `books` isn't public you can't access it from your main-method.

Comment: Are you sure you are inspecing `books` field *after* the insertion?

Comment: What are you looking at when debugging to conclude it is not adding ? The books variable is not updated with a new element after running the Add line within AddBock ?

Comment: On a semantic point of view, one thing that immediately does not make sense is that your add method - which is supposed to add a book - receives an instance of the containing class

Comment: Your question is confusing in sense not sure what the actual problem is. How do you know that book not getting added to list?

Comment: Well it is shameful but it seems problem was all about my list. When I made my list 'public static', it fixed. I just dont know if it is the correct solution for my problem but it seems working fine now

Comment: @KorayDurudogan: making something `static` isn't helpful if you want to understand OOP. Make a public property `Books` that has only a getter and that returns this list. Then you can look at `cls.Books` from your main method and you'll see that the book was added to the list.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the problem is, that `Class1` contains a List that will keep object of type `Class1`. A class containg a list of elements of itself can lead to serious problems. Assuming you want to have a list a of books, I would prefer a solution where you have a class `Book` which contains all the information you want to store about a book. Then you should create a class `BookList` which will manage books. In the example below there is a class BookList which right at the beginning is only able to add a new book. You can extend it with additional functionality like searching a book, deleting a book or giving back the list of all books. Here is my example:

```
class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; } // This is an automatic property
    public string Author { get; set; }
}

class BookList
{
    private var books = new List<Book>();

    public bool AddBook (string title, string author)
    {
         books.Add(new Book { Title = title, Author = author });
         return true;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var bookList = new BookList();
    bookList.AddBook ("Mehmet", "Ali");
}
```

Then you will have a list with one book in it.

Comment: What if he simply wants to create a copy of existing book? To me his code looks *fine* (error-wise), only conclusion "it doesn't work" is wrong. Your code is cleaner, but it doesn't really answers of fix the problem (as there is none in OP code).

Comment: @Sinatr: Keeping in mind that OP is a newbie in OOP, I thought he did something wrong. Class1 contains a list of types of itself. This isn't a quite good idea and will lead to problems. I understood OP wanting to have a list of books and gave him an idea to do that.

Comment: Well, re-writing from beginning is a working tactic. Though if you really want to help a newbie the best is to explain what he did wrong, not simply present him a beautiful code ;)

Comment: @Sinatr: Good point. I will change my answer to add more explanation!